# Unticked PNG files in compizconfig settings manager, how do I open it via the terminal?

Tags: unity, compiz

I recently installed Compiz Config Settings Manager in Ubuntu 11.10.

As I was experimenting some features of it, in image loading tab i mistakenly un-ticked PNG files now I'm not getting (linked PNG system files) dialog-boxes,windows,Unity panel etc.

Kindly some one help.

Comment: i Take you ticked the box again?..

Comment: i dont know how to reopen the app again tried tat for 2 hrs .. can you tell me how to open Compiz Config Settings Manager through terminal.

Comment: ... type `ccsm` in a terminal.